# Compare two objects in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have two objects out of my User model in Laravel. Let's say

```
public function someFunction(User $user) {
    $adminUser = User::where('role', '=', 1);
    if($adminUser === $user) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Is this the proper way to compare two objects in Laravel? As per [PHP Object Comparison](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.object-comparison.php), this should work.

Thanks for any input.

Comment: What do you mean by :`there is no way to compare without accessing the model's specific column` ?

Comment: without doing this: $user->role

Comment: What about defining a method in the user model `isAdmin` and then use it `$user->isAdmin()` ?

Comment: just wondering if this comparison can be done as simple as in http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.object-comparison.php

Comment: If there is one admin => what about comparing ids ?

Comment: `===` will only return `true` if the two variables are pointing to the same object in memory. If you create two objects of the same type, with the same data (as you are trying to check), it will always return `false`, as copies are never exactly the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since `$user` is a `User` instance, you can do this without executing any additional queries:

```
public function someFunction(User $user) {
    return $user->role === 1;
}
```

This code will return `true` if user's role is 1 and `false` if role is not 1.

Comment: there is no way to compare without accessing the model's specific column? (upvoted)

Answer (score 1):

You should try this :

```
public function someFunction(User $user) {

    if($user->role === 1) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

hope this work for you !!!

Comment: there is no way to compare without accessing the model's specific column? (upvoted)